# creating a directory with files in it - bash script

Tags: bash, directory

I would like to create a directory containing two files. The directory has the name of a given argument, therefore the name is not fixed. How can I reference this argument correctly?

The following code returns: "bad substitution". What does this mean?

```
for i in "$@" ; do
        # create dir 
        mkdir "$i"
        # create 2 files
        touch  ${"$i"}/file1
        touch  ${"$i"}/file2
done
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can readily be answered by an internet search. https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=bad+substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is correct:

```
mkdir "$i"
```

Use the same syntax for `touch`:

```
touch  "$i"/file1
```

It's also possible to use `"${i}"` but it's the same thing, just longer.